# php facebook people search how to remove repeat value?

Tags: php

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tom&type=user&access_token=2227470867|2.AQD2FG3bzBMEiDV3.3600.1307905200.0-100001799728875|LowLfLcqSZ9YKujFEpIrlFNVZPQ
```

how to avoid repeat name in facebook people search? in the json code, there have 2 `Thomas Lee`. Thanks.

```
foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
echo $data['name']; // not print the same name.
}
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question.

Comment: The two Thomas Lee are not duplicates. They are different persons. Look at the id.

Comment: @Ancide, yes I know, here are many articles just teach duplicate in array datas. but how to duplicate it in a foreach like this?  Just for study. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast mashup of how you remove duplicates:

```
<?php 
function existsInArray($list, $key, $value){
  foreach($list as $lkey => $lvalue){
    if($lvalue[$key] == $value){
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

$sortedUsers = array();
foreach($status_list['data'] as $data){
  if(!existsInArray($sortedUsers, "id", $data["id"])){
    $sortedUsers[] = $data;
  }
}
```

This will go through the array och users, check if each item exist with the same id in the sorted array. If it doesn't exist, it will be added to the sorted array. Then you have `$sortedUsers` which doesn't contain any duplicates.

Note: However, this is just proof of concept code. So there are probably a lot of performance optimization that could be done. Also, there are probably some built in functionality to which can do this with less user defined code. Why I showed this is to just explain the process.

---

**Edit: Since this answer got accepted I feel obligated to show something which is a little more high quality than proof of concept code. Also because it got mentioned in the comments that it was inefficient.**

So here's easy fix to make this much faster:

```
$sortedUsers = array();
foreach($status_list['data'] as $data){
    $sortedUsers[$data["id"]] = $data;
}
```

This way it will just overwrite the duplicates and will take away the whole process of comparing each item. In worst case this will be O(n) where as the proof of concept code was O(n ^ (n / 2)) in worst case.

Comment: @Ancide, one more question: why duplicates repeat name, but use `$data["id"]` `existsInArray check`? What is the core worked? Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Yes, like I said in the answer it's just to show the process. It would be good for everyone to know why it's inefficient, instead of just saying it is :)

Comment: @fish man: I don't understand what you mean, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Of course I don't mean you need to explain thoroughly why, just give a hint in which direction to look. But it's up to you, it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
$names = Array();

foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   $names[] = $data['name'];
}

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.

foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is easy to understand. but mark the right answer to the first help man. Thanks.

Comment: @fishman: Speed isn't the important thing on Stack Overflow, but I don't mind.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, if I still want to echo `$data['id']`, how to add?

Comment: @fishman: It makes no sense to do that. If you want to maintain the individual `id` data for each result, then you no longer have duplicates.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, Thanks. for I am sorry, I have marked the answser, then refresh the page and see your answer. So, I only make more up +1 to u.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, but do u know how to still print out the $id after check the $name duplicates? if u know, I could make a new question. I just want to study. Thanks again.

Comment: @fishman: As I said above, that would make no sense at all. You'd essentially be outputting an arbitrary ID.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, I add `$id[] = $data['id'];` in first foreach, and do `echo $id`, nothing get. do only `echo $data['id']` in the second foreach, all the id is the forst man's.