# question in array_unique

Tags: php

I am newer studing php. I have asked my question in [php facebook people search how to remove repeat value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323380/php-facebook-people-search-how-to-remove-repeat-value)

but still have some problem want to understand well.

here is the data example.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tom&type=user&access_token=2227470867|2.AQD2FG3bzBMEiDV3.3600.1307905200.0-100001799728875|LowLfLcqSZ9YKujFEpIrlFNVZPQ
```

I want clear the repeat values. here is the answer form Tomalak Geret'kal, thanks him. It can clear the repeat name.

```
$names = Array();

foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   $names[] = $data['name'];
}

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.

foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name;
}
```

for I still want to echo `$id`. I tired 2 method here:

```
$names = Array();

foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   $names[] = $data['name'];
   $id[] = $data['id'];
}

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.

foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name;
   echo $id; // no result
}



$names = Array();

foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   $names[] = $data['name'];
}

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.

foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name;
   echo $data['id']; // all the id is the last people. 
}
```

How to do the right method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array_unique($status_list['data']);

foreach ($data as $i) {
    echo $i['name'];
    echo $i['id'];
}
```

By using `$names = array_unique($names);` you only put all the names in the array `$names`.

EDIT: well i agree with Tomalak Geret'kal, cause it makes no sense to echo the ID but you could try the following:

```
foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   $names[] = $data['name'];
   $ids[] = $data['id'];
}

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.
$ids = array_unique($ids);  // not print the same name.

$i = 0

foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name;
    echo $ids[$i];
    $i ++;
}
```

Comment: `$status_list['data']` already contains no dups. The OP, for some reason, wants to collapse the dataset so that there's one entry per name, maintaining the map from that name to _one_ of the IDs it represents. (And I refuse to write code for that because it's meaningless!)

Comment: make up to `+0` . I have tried add `array_unique` in `$status_list['data']`, but just get the first `name` and `id`. I think may be store them all into `array` then do the next step, but I am newer, not know how to do. Thanks.

Comment: @fishman: Do not vote for answers that you do not understand just because somebody else downvoted them.

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense.

You only had duplicates because you were discarding all information other than "Name", which was not a unique field.

When you bring the `id` field (which *is* unique) into the picture, you no longer have any duplicates in the result.

So, just write:

```
foreach ($status_list['data'] as $data) {
   echo $data['name'] . " " . $data['id'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: As I say, I just for study. pls do not think the real station. If I want compare `name` no repeat, then print all the json item data, `name, id ...  if there will have more`. How to do?

Comment: no matter, do not stand in the real situation, but stand in technical. how to judge in a foreach like this. compare one part is not repeat, then print all the data in this dom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = Array();
$names=array("0"=>1,"1"=>"1","2"=>"2","3"=>"2","4"=>"23"); //same value in array

$names = array_unique($names);  // not print the same name.

foreach ($names as $name) {
      echo "\n\r".$name;
}
```